# Ayuda al extraer tabla de una página web usando html_table()

Tags: html, r, table, scraping

Deseo obtener los valores de la tabla de datos que se muestra a continuación:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para lo cual uso el paquete `rvest`. El código que uso es el siguiente:Primero cargo la página web

```
pagina_web <- read_html("https://www.sunedu.gob.pe/avances-licenciamiento/")
```

El css de la tabla de la imagen es el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por lo que ahora uso la siguiente sintaxis para extraer la tabla:

```
universidades_html <- html_node(pagina_web,"table.table")
universidades_texto <- html_table(universidades_html, header = T)
```

Pero me indica el siguiente error:

```
"Error in UseMethod("html_table") : 
  no applicable method for 'html_table' applied to an object of class "xml_missing""
```

No sé a que se debe este error, podrían ayudarme.
Y como tendría que corregir el error para poder conseguir la tabla.

**Muchas gracias de antemano.**

Answer (score 0):

Eso sucede por que esta cargado en javascript

Segun lo que comentan en el primer comentario aqui
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51801321/getting-xml-nodeset-0-when-using-html-nodes-from-rvest-package-in-r][1]